# Extract iCloud Password from iTunes backup

Tags: ios, itunes, icloud

How can I extract my forgotten iCloud Password from iTunes backup?
I've tried to use iTunes backup extractor and the I locate accounts.db file
Then I use sqlite browser to explore it,I found only the iCloud mail(which is I have already) and other mails..
is there any ideas please

Answer (score 2):

Your iCloud password is not preserved within an iTunes backup, unless you stashed it somewhere intentionally.

If you've forgotten your iCloud password, your only real option is to go through the password recovery procedure on [iforgot.apple.com](http://iforgot.apple.com)